# How to run Scrapy from within a Python script And Block Script From Resuming

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my spider file amzspider.py

```
import sys
from scrapy.http import Request
import datetime
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector



class amazonScraperSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "Amazon_Scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    urls=[]

    def __init__(self,url,product_file,asin_file):
        self.product_file=product_file
        self.asin_file=asin_file
        self.url=[url]
        self.start_urls = [url]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        Tops = hxs.select("//*[@class='zg_more_link']/@href").extract()
        Tops.append = self.url
        for Top in Tops:
            yield Request(Top, callback = self.parseTopsPages)

    def parseTopsPages(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        PageLinks = hxs.select("//div[@id='zg_paginationWrapper']//li/a/@href").extract()
        for PageLink in PageLinks:
            yield Request(PageLink, callback = self.parseProducts)

    def parseProducts(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        products = hxs.select("//div[@class='zg_itemWrapper']//div[@class='zg_title']/a/@href").extract()
        for productlink in products:
            x = productlink.strip(' \t\n\r')
            x1 = '/'.join(x.split('/')[:6])
            self.urls.append(x1)
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        f=open(self.product_file,"w")
        f1=open(self.asin_file,"w")
        for url in self.urls:
            f.write(url+"\n")
            f.flush()
        for url in self.urls:
            f.write(url.replace("http://www.","")+"\n")
            f.flush()
        for url in self.urls:
            f.write("http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/" + url.split("/")[-1]+"\n")
            f.flush()
        for url in self.urls:
            f.write("amazon.com/gp/product/" + url.split("/")[-1]+"\n")
            f.flush()
        f.close()
        for url in self.urls:
            f1.write(url.split("/")[-1]+"\n")
            f1.flush()
        f1.close()
```

I call it from controller.py and I want to wait for it to finish (Block Thread) and only then continue with controller.py after it's done scraping work.

I call it this way:

```
spider = amzspider.amazonScraperSpider(url, settings['product_file'], settings['asins_file'])
```

The problem controller.py continues executing code without thread block of amzspider.py

Answer (score 0):

Your `main()` function just creates an instance; it doesn't actually make it do anything. You should really call:

```
spider = amzspider.amazonScraperSpider(url, settings['product_file'], settings['asins_file'])
```

in `controller.py`. This will actually give you access to the instance; you don't need `main()`. You can then *use* the instance:

```
response = get_a_response() # whatever you do here
spider.parse(response) # give the spider work to do
```

Etc.

Comment: so I should remove def main from amzspider.py and call it with your code in controller.py?

Comment: Yes; your `main` doesn't really add anything.

Comment: Ok I changed that. But still controller.py continues with execution of the code before the scraper has finished

Comment: You haven't actually shown controller.py, so I can't tell you anything about that. Also, creating the instance doesn't actually mean the spider starts scraping

Comment: well my controller.py is very simple `http://pastebin.com/9SRZvd8y` also I think you're right it most likly it didn't start scraping I call it not correctly any ideas?

Comment: got it done. Using reactor, http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?highlight=reactor#run-scrapy-from-a-script I have other issue now the script saves those 2 text files. And my controller.py tries to open it. `new_asins=set(open(settings['asins_new'],"r").read().split("\n")[:-1])` but i get the following error `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found`

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen the code for how you create your threads it seems you want to call `join()` on the thread running `amzspider.main`.

From the [Python threading manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html):

> Other threads can call a thread’s join() method. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated.

Comment: I just do python controller.py and the amzspider.main is how I call it

Comment: also this method worked fine when I used Selenium Web Driver for scraping only with Scrapy it doesn't work